# Python + MongoDB, how to dynamically choose DB Collection

Tags: python, mongodb, reflection, collections, introspection

How can I dynamically point to a particular collection name in MongoDB with Python?

I receive data from any 1 of a few dozen sensors in my network, and I want to store the raw data into a db collection named for the sensor.

```py
# Server Parameters
host = '1.2.3.4'
port = 27017
client = MongoClient(host, port)
db = client.myDB                # use database myDB

# receive data from sensors
# {"sensorName":"...", "x":"...", "y":"...", "z":"...", "time":"..."}

db.SensorA.insert_one({...})    # record raw data in the collection for SensorA
db.SensorB.insert_one({...})
db.SensorC.insert_one({...})
```

Instead of explicitly writing `db.SensorName.insert_one({...})`, I'd like to somehow reference the given sensor/collection name.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can reference the collection names using this syntax too:

```
    db["SensorA"].insert_one({...})
```

you would do it like this given a list of data this will insert the documents in the proper collection based on the sensorName attribute of the data:

```
    for data in data_list:
        db[data["sensorName"]].insert_one({...})
```